# Google chrome and Safari hover div doesn't hide after moving mouse away

Tags: html, css, hover

I have this html page: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84321529/Fensternorm/index.html

There is a bigger `div` when you hover products and it contains more information about the product and one button. This content is hidden with `overflow:hidden` and everything is done with pure css solution.

I have no idea why is that problem with google chrome (Version 29.0.1547.66 m) and safari(5.1.7). Tested it on Firefox on mac & windows and on IE>7 and it works fine.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `position: absolute;` in these class: `.product-list li div {}`

```
.product-list li div {
    width:184px;
    color:#999;
    line-height:15px;
    position:absolute; // <--
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable absolute positioning on the div inside of the li and, in all probability, you should have a working solution.